# Convert char to int in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, numbers, char, int

I am trying to convert a char to an int that's passed to a method:

```
volume('10');

void volume(char* number) {
  for (int i = 0; i < atoi(number); i++) {
    // do something 10 times
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What output do you get? How does that compare to what you expected?

Comment: Do you mean `"10"`?

Comment: Always compile with all warnings, and ignore none of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
volume('10');

void volume(char* number) {
  for (int i = 0; i < atoi(number); i++) {
    // do something 10 times
  }
}
```

to:

```
volume("10"); // <<< note the double quotes !

void volume(const char* number) { // <<< note the const
  for (int i = 0; i < atoi(number); i++) {
    // do something 10 times
  }
}
```

NB: if you had compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) then the above errors would have been immediately apparent. Try to get into the habit of doing this and do not ignore warnings - they are there for a good reason and will often save you a lot of time debugging problems at run-time that could have been fixed at compile-time.

Comment: +1 for changing the parameter type from `char*` to `const char*`. It would be also good if you explicitly mention the reason in your answer, so the OP can know it.